parted + how to automate parted answers file
we want to give answers file to parted command
first here manual example that works fine of on our RedHat 7.9 server
parted /dev/sda  resizepart 3 100%
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
parted: invalid token: 3    <-- first answer
Fix/Ignore/Cancel? Fix  <-- second answer
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 167772160 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? Fix <-- third answer
Partition number? 3  <-- fourth answer
End?  [73.0GB]?  <-- last empty answer "\n"
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

so we try the following with echo ( to automate the process )
echo -e "3\nFix\nFix\n3\n" | parted /dev/sda  resizepart 3 100%
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 167772160 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.

but echo isn't works to gives the right answers parameters to parted command
the problem is that we can't use expect command since this command not installed on our redhat servers ( and we cant installed it because security aspect )
any idea about how to gives parted the answers parameters ? or maybe how to use parted -s ?

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78838650/how-to-automate-parted-answers-file
